# How to properly set up a For- In Loop within a Guard statement?

Tags: ios, json, swift, guard

I'm trying to set up a loop to retrieve info from inside a json dictionary but the dictionary is in a guard statement:

```
 guard let resultsDictionary = jsonDictionary["result"] as? [[String : Any]]?,
    let costDictionary = resultsDictionary?[0],
    let cost = costDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],

    let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any]{
    for air in airbnb {
      let airbnbUS = air["USD"] as Int
      let airbnbLocal = air["CHF"] as Int
    }
    else {
      print("Error: Could not retrieve dictionary")
      return;
  }
```

When I do this I get multiple errors:

> Expected 'else' after 'guard' condition,
>    Variable declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body,
>    Braced block of statements is an unused closure

I'm not sure why it doesnt work

Comment: Your `guard` logic is far off - the syntax is `guard statements else { /* error handling */ } /* the regular logic using airbnb */`

Comment: While this question should likely be closed for being opinion based, it would be great if there was a standardized way to express this. To me, @i_am_jorf second way should be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `guard` is:

```
guard [expression] else {
  [code-block]
}
```

You want to use `if` instead:

```
if let resultsDictionary = jsonDictionary["result"] as? [[String : Any]]?,
 let costDictionary = resultsDictionary?[0],
 let cost = costDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
 let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any]{
    ...for loop here...
} else {
    ...error code here...
}
```

Or you can say:

```
guard let resultsDictionary = jsonDictionary["result"] as? [[String : Any]]?,
 let costDictionary = resultsDictionary?[0],
 let cost = costDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
 let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any] else {
    ...error code here...
    return  // <-- must return here
}

...for loop here, which will only run if guard passes...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you should use `if let` like:

```
    if let resultsDictionary = jsonDictionary["result"] as? [[String : Any]]?,
    let costDictionary = resultsDictionary?.first,
    let cost = costDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
    let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any] {
      for air in airbnb {
        let airbnbUS = air["USD"] as Int
        let airbnbLocal = air["CHF"] as Int
        ...any other statements...
      }
    } else {
      print("Error: Could not retrieve dictionary")
      return
    }
```

[This can you help to decide when to use `guard`](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/)

Comment: No need to cast as optional array `jsonDictionary["result"] as? [[String : Any]]` and resultsDictionary is misleading naming for an array